# R Shiny Error: Error in ... : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable - Access reactive data in global environment?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, reactive-programming

I am trying to make a program that fetches data about a patient that a user selects from a select input (pnum). I am trying to add a new column, stampDate, to pdata although when I run this:

```
library(shiny)
require(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(reshape)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  chan1 <- reactive({odbcConnect('database', uid='username')})
  queryString1 <- reactive({sprintf("SELECT PatientNum, TimeStamp as Time_Stamp, SWStatus,SWMeanQoS1 as EMAT,SWS3DisplayValue as S3,SWS4DisplayValue as S4,SysDysIndexNoEFLR as SDI
                    FROM Biometrics..WcdHeartSounds
                    WHERE PatientNum = ",input$pnum)})
  output$pdata <- renderDataTable({
  rdata <- reactive({sqlQuery(chan1(), queryString1())})
  })

  odbcCloseAll()

  pdata$stampDate <- as.Date(pdata$Time_Stamp, "%y-%m-%d")

})
```

I receive this error message:

```
Error in pdata$Time_Stamp : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Should I be looking to make the data table pdata accessible in the global environment and have it update every time the user inputs a new patient, or is there another way to subset it while it is still just a reactive function? I am fairly new to RStudio and Shiny and there is nobody at my workplace to assist me so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have a typeo  `pdata` should be `rdata` right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I still get the same error regardless

Answer (score 0):

First, check your dataframe, you did not pass the `%d` in [sprintf()](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Strings/Creating_strings_from_variables/):

```
sprintf("SELECT PatientNum, TimeStamp as Time_Stamp, SWStatus,
         SWMeanQoS1 as EMAT,SWS3DisplayValue as S3,SWS4DisplayValue as S4,
         SysDysIndexNoEFLR as SDI FROM Biometrics..WcdHeartSounds 
         WHERE PatientNum = %d;", input$pnum)
```

Also, consider updating dataframe before `renderDataTable({})`

```
rdata <- reactive({sqlQuery(chan1(), queryString1())})
rdata$stampDate <- as.Date(rdata$Time_Stamp, "%y-%m-%d")

output$pdata <- renderDataTable({rdata})
```